# How to search through multiple xml files for the occurence of a string in between 2 tags in linux?

Tags: xml, linux, string, ubuntu, grep

I have around 100 xml files in which there is an inconsistency of how to euro sign (€) is displayed as the character or as (`&amp;euro`).

First to prove that these 2 strings occured in the same files, i used grep :

```
grep -e "&amp;euro" -e "€" -R /home/xml/ -o
```

`&amp;euro` only occurs between the tags `<conditions>` and `<directions>`.

e.g.

```
<directions> text text text : price : 19.99 &amp;euro text text&amp;euro </directions>
<conditions><tag><tag2> text text text &amp;euro text&amp;euro </tag2></tag></conditions>
```

I would like to search for the occurence of the € sign in any strings in between these tags.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Use a XML parser?  `xmlstarlet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it with element 'directions':

```
find . -name "*.xml" | xargs grep "<directions>.*\&amp;euro.*<\/directions>"
```

Same can be applied to 'conditions' element.